# Switch from mock backend to real backend on application start

Tags: javascript, http, angular5

I have an Angular 5 application that I want to be able to start from either a mock backend or a real backend depending on an environment variable.

This is my environment file:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    mockBackend: true
};
```

I want to be able to have this sort of structure:

> AppModule
>
> > SharedAppModules
> >
> > AppModule, imports SharedAppModules and adds what is necessary.
> >
> > MockAppModule, imports SharedAppModules and adds what is necessary:

```
 MockBackendService,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    {
      provide: Http,
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
      useFactory: mockHttpFactory
    }
```

My goal would be to do in main.ts:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
if(environment.mockBackend) {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MockAppModule);
} else {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

But I have an error from Angular saying it did not find anything to bootstrap. Has anybody already tried to do the same thing or have any idea to achieve the same goal differently?

Comment: Please, don't paraphrase errors. Quote them instead. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem, since it's unclear what's wrong. Plunker or Stackblitz would be ok.

Comment: I achieved my goal following the poster in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500389/how-to-load-modules-conditionally-in-angular-2